# How to drag a MapPolygon on a Map

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to drag a MapPolygon on a SwiftUI Map. I have created this example code,
to show it is not dragging the `MapPolygon` smoothly and accurately.

What is a more appropriate way to drag a whole `MapPolygon` on a Map smoothly and accurately?

The problem as I see it, is the translation of all points of the `MapPolygon` (doDrag),
this is not a good way to do translation, but I cannot find a better one.

(ios-17 and MacCatalyst)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDraging = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ToolbarView(isDraging: $isDraging)
            MapViewer(isDraging: $isDraging)
        }
    }
}

struct MapViewer: View {
    @Binding var isDraging: Bool
    @State private var modes = MapInteractionModes.all
    
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(
        MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.68, longitude: 139.75), distance: 4000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0)
    )
    
    @State private var polyPoints = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.682890728577135, longitude: 139.74688521853778),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.682457291364656, longitude: 139.7513297533676),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.679605242840324, longitude: 139.74859855588522)]
    
    var body: some View {
        MapReader { reader in
            Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: modes) {
                MapPolygon(coordinates: polyPoints)
                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    .foregroundStyle(.purple.opacity(0.3))
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { drag in
                    if isDraging {
                        doDrag(drag)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        .mapStyle(.imagery)
        .mapControlVisibility(.hidden)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onChange(of: isDraging) {
            if isDraging { modes.subtract(.all) }
            else { modes.update(with: .all) }
        }
    }
    
    // this is not working well
    func doDrag(_ drag: DragGesture.Value) {
        for i in polyPoints.indices {
            let p = MKMapPoint(polyPoints[i])
            let newP = MKMapPoint(x: p.x + drag.translation.width, y: p.y + drag.translation.height)
            polyPoints[i] = newP.coordinate
        }
    }
 
}

struct ToolbarView: View {
    @Binding var isDraging: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { isDraging.toggle() }) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "move.3d")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(isDraging ? .red : .blue)
                Text(isDraging ? "Drag on" : "Drag off")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(isDraging ? .red : .blue)
            }.frame(width: 80, height: 60)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        .background(Color.white)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

Tried to translate all points of the MapPolygon, but that does not give a acceptable results.

Comment: One reason why it won't perform well is that you are applying the drag translation cumulatively. Instead of adding the drag translation to the starting position, you are adding it to the current position. So as soon as the drag translation is anything more than minimal, the polygon flies out of frame.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a better way to do it than to update the points individually. But as I mentioned in a comment, one reason why it wasn't working well is because you were applying the drag translation cumulatively. Instead of adding the drag translation to the starting position, you were adding it to the current position. So as soon as the drag translation was anything more than minimal, the polygon was flying out of frame.

I would suggest these changes:

- Capture the polygon position at start-of-drag and use this for all updates.
- At end-of-drag, reset the start position, so that it is ready for another drag.
- In `doDrag`, I would prepare a new array and assign this in one operation, instead of updating the items in the array. This might help to trigger less view updates.

When I tried these changes, I found that the polygon hardly moved when you tried to drag it. It seems that the drag offset needs to be scaled by a factor of approx. 25 to make it work. I don't know if this is related to the camera height or if there is a way to find the scaling factor instead of hard-coding it. You could make it the topic of a new question if you don't know the answer either.

*EDIT* With a bit more experimentation, I found that the scaling factor can be calculated as approximately: (MapCamera distance) / 160. I don't know if this is documented anywhere.

So here is a version that works a bit better:

```swift
struct MapViewer: View {
    @Binding var isDragging: Bool
    @State private var modes = MapInteractionModes.all

    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(
        MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.68, longitude: 139.75), distance: 4000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0)
    )

    @State private var polyPoints = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.682890728577135, longitude: 139.74688521853778),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.682457291364656, longitude: 139.7513297533676),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.679605242840324, longitude: 139.74859855588522)
    ]

    @State private var dragPointsBegin = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    let mapScalingFactor: CGFloat = 25 // where can this be obtained from?

    var body: some View {
        MapReader { reader in
            Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: modes) {
                MapPolygon(coordinates: polyPoints)
                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    .foregroundStyle(.purple.opacity(0.3))
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { drag in
                    if isDragging {
                        doDrag(drag.translation)
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { _ in

                    // Reset the start position, ready for another drag
                    dragPointsBegin = polyPoints
                }
            )
        }
        .mapStyle(.imagery)
        .mapControlVisibility(.hidden)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onChange(of: isDragging) {
            if isDragging {
                modes.subtract(.all)

                // Capture a snapshot of the polygon points
                dragPointsBegin = polyPoints
            }
            else { modes.update(with: .all) }
        }
    }

    func doDrag(_ translation: CGSize) {
        var draggedPoints = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        draggedPoints.reserveCapacity(dragPointsBegin.count)
        for point in dragPointsBegin {
            let p = MKMapPoint(point)
            draggedPoints.append(
                MKMapPoint(
                    x: p.x + (translation.width * mapScalingFactor),
                    y: p.y + (translation.height * mapScalingFactor)
                )
                .coordinate
            )
        }
        polyPoints = draggedPoints
    }
}
```

It might also help if `polyPoints` and/or `dragPointsBegin` would be arrays of `MKMapPoint`, because this might reduce the computational overhead. But if the polygon only consists of a handful of points, I don't suppose it makes much difference.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer gave me some ideas,
 but it still uses the polygon coordinates to do the translation.
 I was hoping for something like `MapPolygon(..).onDrag { ... }` where the `MapPolygon` is wrapped
 by something that is MapContent compatible and draggable.